# Manage memory when creating continuous output to PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell

The PowerShell script below runs continuously and generates output.  This is a simplified version of a script which which I use to monitor processes running on my computer.

```
while ($true) { 
    get-date
    start-sleep 1
}
```

I run this process in the the PowerShell ISE (Windows 10, PowerShell v5.1).

When this script runs, the memory used by the PowerShell ISE (powershell_ise.exe) increases continuously.  Stopping the process stops the memory utilization increase.

Adding `clear-host` to the process does not help.  The script below also uses an ever-increasing amount of RAM.

```
while ($true) { 
    clear-host  # <=== Added
    get-date
    start-sleep 1
}
```

How can I limit the memory consumed by this continuously running process?

Comment: how about: `[gc]::Collect()`?

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 6+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: I would like to know why garbage collection is needed here.  My loop isn't creating anything new.

Comment: *"my loop isn't creating anything new"*, oh, but it is! Each loop creates a place in memory where the first iteration of `Get-Date` was stored, regardless if it was disposed of right after. This is why `[gc]::Collect()` "*frees*" that space in memory by manually calling in the garbage collection that only gets called under certain circumstances.

Comment: @[Abraham Zinala], I'd love to learn more about this.  How does a simple call to ``get-date``` take up increasing amounts of memory?  There are no references to this object.

Comment: I just deleted the following:  @Abraham Zinala, ```[gc]::Collect()``` seems to work. Thank you! If you'd like to turn this into an answer, I'll accept it. – mherzog Jan 3 at 21:38.

Comment: The reason I deleted my comment is that ```[bc]:Collect()``` helps but does not solve the issue.  Even when not running PowerShell from using the ISE (using VS Code), memory utilization of my process continues to grow.

Comment: Because memory is still being used. You can try assigning the cmdlets you're not using to `$null` and seeing if that helps: `$null = Clear-Host` and `$null = Start-Sleep 1` so it can be discarded at run time.